# post a local file to a rest endpoint with angularjs & cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, transloadit

I'm trying to post a video recorded by a user to a rest endpoint.  The user will record a video and then my app will post it to TransloadIt.  I'm currently using the FileTransfer Plugin from Cordova.  My app just exits when it runs though.  Here is what I have.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fcbf6fdba12071b68fae

I can't find any examples that are posting a file submitted from a web form.  The video in this case is a local file on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Recently [someone reported a similar Cordova issue](https://github.com/transloadit/uppy/issues/1001) about [Uppy](https://uppy.io) and it turned out that Cordova didn't support the File object and needed to use Blob instead. I suspect that might be plaguing your integration now too. The [issue has been reported at Cordova](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/issues/240) as well. In the meantime [Uppy merged a workaround](https://github.com/transloadit/uppy/pull/1034) for this problem that you could likely apply to your project as well.